# To use multer to save files in different folders?

Tags: node.js, express, url, multer

I am using multer for file storage in express, however when i use req.params.event in the file i get undefined. Why is this happening. Without req.params.event i cant categorize my uploads in folder

```
  var multer = require('multer');


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        console.log(req.params.event);  //This console log is undefined
        callback(null, './uploads');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now());
    }
});

   var upload= multer({
        storage: storage
    }).single('userPhoto');

module.exports={upload:upload};
```

This is my route for the event

```
 app.get('/events/:event', (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.params.event); // here working perfectly
    res.render('event.hbs', {
    });
})
```

This is upload route

```
    app.post('/events/upload',upload,function(req,res){
  console.log("uploded")
});
```

Even req.params is empty in multer

Comment: Where are you using the multer middleware in your route?

Comment: I am uploading an image file to server using multer.

Comment: But you have to use it in the route like: `app.get('/event/:event', multer({}), (req, res) => {})`

Comment: nd trying to use the url to categorize the image in folder using multer

Comment: hmmm.... i dont know that, i am using multer for first time, the file upload was fine.

Comment: let me check this

Comment: The file uploaded? :O

Comment: Yup...you can see my git code to check it

Comment: https://github.com/alpitanand/Business

Comment: You have `'/events/upload'` route in your GitHub that does `upload(req,res,function(err) {})` - this is missing in your question.

Comment: Ok, i get it, but since i am using ajax and browser is displaying event/sing route wont the req.params will get this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165333/discussion-between-alpit-anand-and-faizuddin-mohammed).

Answer (score 7):

```
                Quit late for this answer, but maybe it will help to someone
```

**When using multer for uploading file, params and query of request object does not populated before file, so you can not access it before uploading of file, as in your case under multer.diskStorage.**

**similary req.body may not have been fully populated before uploading of file. It depends on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.**

**you can check here for req.body :**

https://github.com/expressjs/multer#diskstorage

**Now Answer to save files under different folder using multer :**

1) First of all you should use req.body.event to categorize folders, i.e transmit event using body not by using query and params

2) Now during posting of file from client side reverse the order of event and file, i.e post event first then file

**You may refer to this code that is working well for me**

```
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (req.body.event == 'test') {
      cb(null, "images/test"); // it will upload inside test under images
    } else {
      cb(null, "images/try"); // it will upload inside try under images
    }
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + "-" + file.originalname);
  }
});
```

Now from client side say using postman:

[image]

**As you can see in image, event key is placed before image key**

Now it will detect body and will able to upload files into different folders test and try as in example code.